# Column's value as table name

Tags: php, mysql

I don't have enough experience with mysql language.
I need a query that include a subquery where I select something from another table with table name like a value from current table's column value.
The query is something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `action_{$id}` as `action` INNER JOIN `{$id}` as `table` ON
    (
       (
       action.father_id='0' AND //some condition
       )
       OR
       (
            action.father_id<>'0' AND 
        table.type_id IN
        (
            SELECT type FROM **action_{$id}.father_id** WHERE type_id='{$id}'
            )
       )
    )
```

In this example action_{$id}.father_id(or action.father_id) contains the name of another table from my database.

Please excuse my bad english.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible and indicates a structural error in your table design.

`action_{$id}.father_id** WHERE type_id='{$id}'`
Maybe it's just me but isn't that rather redundant?

Comment: I know that I will have an error but I was thinking that is something similar,another syntax...
Anyway with something like this my query should be very slow. Thank you for this answer(this is a great community)!

Comment: It's possible. But your answer is right. Bad idea to teach a man to shoot his leg himself.